# reading data from websocket in js

Tags: javascript, qt, websocket, client

i have a service, which uses QWebSocketServer. My server is able to handle client requests and send several events to client (without any request, it is important). I've tested my server with QWebSocket class like shown in Qt example. All works perfectly.

Now i want to implement frontend in js. And i've faced with one thing which i cannot understand. If client sends request to server, server's answer can be received on client side, but if server sends data without client request, i'm not able to receive this data.

In my js script i have usual code:

```
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
```

So, why i can't receive data from server without request and what should i do for getting the ability to receive that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

server has been sending messages from another thread, that was the cause of problem